# What's Mahā-mokṣa? Which scriptures refer to the Mahāmṛtyuñjaya mantra as the “Mahā-Mokṣa mantra (महा-मोक्ष मंत्र)”?

Tags: shiva, mantras, moksha, devi

In some of the books and blogs, I came across the term "Mahā-Mokṣa (महामोक्ष) Mantra" being used for the Mahāmṛtyuñjaya Mantra.

For instance:

[This book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NTcpEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT114&dq=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7+%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT_LWEi772AhWhsVYBHbqdAicQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0&f=false) says -

> In Sanātan Hinduism, this mantra is also called Prāṇarakṣaka (life-saver) and **Mahā-mokṣa Mantra** (mantra for great peace).

And so does [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SngmDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7+%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT_LWEi772AhWhsVYBHbqdAicQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%20%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0&f=false)  -

> **It is known as Śiva’s Mahā Mokṣa mantra, or “Great Liberation” mantra**, and is said to impart the experience of our eternal Divine nature.

Further, as per the [wikisource](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%9D-%E0%A4%A3):- in the Varṇa-Uddhāra Tantra,  there's references to the great goddess being referred as **'mahāmokṣa-pradāyinīm' i.e., the bestower of the Great-Salvation.**

> वर्णो-द्धारतन्त्रे उक्तं यथा । “रक्तोत्पलनिभां रम्यां रक्त-
> पङ्कजलोचनाम् । अष्टादशभुजां भीमां **महामोक्ष-
> प्रदायिनीम्** ।

---

### Questions:

1. Is there such a thing specifically known as Mahāmokṣa (महामोक्ष), which is different from the traditional Mokṣa?

   - *Or the usage of "Mahā" is just as a way of embellishment just like sometimes we say Mahā-Lakṣmī (although sometimes there's indeed a difference between the Lakṣmī and the Mahā-Lakshmi)*.

2. Does any scripture refers to the Mahāmṛtyuñjaya mantra as the “Mahā-mokṣa mantra (महामोक्ष मन्त्र)”?

Comment: Maha-Moksha is related to Kundalini and the six chakras (the term can be found in Rudra-yamala at various places e.g. first patalam- verse 86) Either, this has No connections with Mrutunjaya, or there is something more to be found. See the subtext [here](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.505874/page/461/mode/2up)

Comment: Thanks @Proxy ... *" Either, this has No connections with Mrutunjaya, or there is something more to be found."* - I'll hope and pray for the latter. :P